# ffmpeg and ffplay with same inputs have different outputs

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a 1 minute mp4 video that was output from PowerDirector 18.
When I run `ffplay` as:

```
ffplay -i t1.mp4 -vf eq=brightness=0.5
```

It does what I expect. However, when I run `ffmpeg` as:

```
ffmpeg -i t1.mp4 t1-2.avi -vf eq=brightness=0.5
```

--or--

```
ffmpeg -i t1.mp4 t1-3.mov -vf eq=brightness=0.5
```

--or--

```
ffmpeg -i t1.mp4 t1-4.mp4 -vf eq=brightness=0.5
```

the output is the same as the input and not like it was
with `ffplay`. Having said that, a part of the `ffmpeg` output says:

```
"Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 't1.mp4':"
```

2 questions.

1. what is the warning above
2. why didn't `ffmpeg` do the conversion?

I have a feeling the answer to the 1st question may answer the 2nd question.

I am totally lost at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Running version  n4.4-80-gbf87bdd3f6-20210819 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

## Location of options is important

Basic syntax:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [input options] -i input [output options] output
```

The [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) for the `-filter:v`/`-vf` option indicates that it is an **output option**.

## Solution

Put the `-vf` option in the proper location. Your command should be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf eq=brightness=0.5 output.mov
```

#### Questions

> 1. what is the warning, `Trailing option(s) found in the command: may be ignored`?

Options placed after the last output are considered to be **trailing options**. This means that ffmpeg doesn't know if you want the option to be applied to the input or the output, so therefore the option may get ignored.

> 2. why didn't ffmpeg do the conversion?

Your output file was created, so it was actually converted from MP4 to MOV, but the `-vf` option was misplaced as a trailing option and was ignored.

Comment: Thank you.It works well. I watched 1 youtube video of ffmpeg and i am certain (?) their example did it the way i tried.